# How to merge all the elements of a vector into only one elements in R?

Tags: r, string

Myvector

```
A = c("a", "b", "c")
```

I would like to have this

```
B= "a|b|c"
```

Comment: `B <- paste0(A, collapse = '|')`

Comment: Fantastic! It works. Thank you